# Animations performance in internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, svelte, velocity.js

I am maintaining a legacy code at work that runs on internet explorer 7, and I have performance issues on the old hardware.

Css animation being not supported in IE7, I've tried jquery animate but the results were horrible, I've tried to replace theme with Velocity.js, I've seen some minor performance gains but still not enough.

```js
containerReference
  .delay(3000)
  .velocity({
    top: '25px'
  }, {
    'easing': 'linear',
    'duration': 1600
  })
;
```

Any idea how to improve performance ?

Do you know about any tiny compiled framework that could help (sveltJS maybe) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [F12 developer Network tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85)) to check which part will spend too much time to load the website. Then, refer to the following article to improve the website performance.

[Improving UI responsiveness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn255009(v=vs.94))

[Best Practices for Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa291563(v=vs.94)#MainContent)

[Three Ways To Improve Performance Using Caching In ASP.NET MVC Applications](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Three-Ways-To-Improve-80fd7e3a)

[8 Ways to Improve Your Website Performance](https://www.monitis.com/blog/8-ways-to-improve-your-website-performance/)